# making a variable equal to another variable so it cannot add or subtract anymore

Tags: batch-file

I am new to game programming in batch, and I am trying to make a variable equal to another one, and if the operator adds or subtract another variable that is not the max value, it won't add or subtract anymore. My batch file is:

```
if %num1% geq %num2% set /a num1=%num1% == %num2%
echo number: %num1%/%num2%
echo 1) add number
echo 2) quit
set /p input=
if %input% == 1 set /a num1=%num1%+1
if %input% == 2 exit
```

if there's a similar question to that one, please go nice on me.

Comment: Why in the world would you program a game using "batch"? If you have to do such strange things, then use PowerShell.

Comment: Not sure what `if %num1% geq %num2% set /a num1=%num1% == %num2%` is expected to do - it'll generate a syntax error because `==` is not an arithmetic operator.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample that might help:

```
@echo off
set max=50
set num=20
:loop
set /p "input=Enter number to add - you now have %num% units: "
set /a t=num + input
if %t% LEQ %max% (
      set num=%t%
  ) else (
      echo That's too high - %max% is the limit!
)
echo %num%
goto :loop
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure on batch unless you mean shell programs or DOS mode shell programs for batch, however you can use an atomic variable with a C++ class and overload the =, + and - operator to use test and set, making sure that assign it correctly, you can then create mini programs performing you're operations that you can access using eval or system functions in you're program or with %fct% or `fct`